# Global Search in salesforce

Tags: sosl, global-search

I was searching for record by passing some value in global search but I am getting different result whenever add '0' prefix to it. When i am searching for '012345' i got three record but when i search for '12345' it returned two record. Both the result is different record. It look like search only match for exact value in the field Is it correct ? Can we modify the search option so it can return same record in both case (Prefix with 0 || Without prefix '0' ). Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify the behavior of Salesforce Global Search or SOSL, the full-text search functionality used throughout Salesforce.

SOSL searches match at the start of a token, [where](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm)

> The search engine splits record information separated by spaces or punctuation into separate tokens

You can use wildcards to match in the middle and at the end of your search, but not at the beginning. That's just not how the underlying search technology works.

If you need different search behavior, consider building it yourself using SOQL, where you have a bit more control and flexibility.

Comment: Thanks David !!